# ruby shoots my output on to separate lines unncessarily

Tags: ruby, arrays, string-formatting

I have written a dice rolling program that saves both the number of sides a die has as well as the roll of a die. When I try and output the two pieces together ruby decides to throw the two pieces on to separate lines. Why when writing:

```
what_has_rolled.zip(how_many_sides) do |die, sides| print "Your d#{sides} rolled a #{die}" end
```

does my output look like:

Your d6 rolled a
Your d5 rolled a
Your d4 rolled a
Your d rolled a 4
Your d rolled a 1
Your d rolled a 3

as opposed to:

Your d6 rolled a 4
Your d5 rolled a 1
Your d4 rolled a 3

and how can I write it so its printed correctly?

Comment: Looks to me your real problem is in what_has_rolled.zip(how_many_sides), it's not yielding three pairs of numbers.

Comment: Post your method source code for us to debug.

Comment: Hey, I replied to Tom French's response under here, it was a mistake that I made where I initialized my array to (3) before adding elements at the end -- the console wasn't printing nil so i never saw it in the output until Tom mentioned it. All is well now, it was just a stupid mistake. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your length of `how_many_sides` is shorter than the length of `what_has_rolled`. For example, I can reproduce the output above like this:

```
how_many_sides = [6,5,4]    
what_has_rolled = [nil,nil,nil,4,1,3]
what_has_rolled.zip(how_many_sides) do |die, sides| puts "Your d#{sides} rolled a #{die}" end
```

gives me the same output as you got:

```
Your d6 rolled a 
Your d5 rolled a 
Your d4 rolled a 
Your d rolled a 4
Your d rolled a 1
Your d rolled a 3
```

This is because when the arguments to [`Array.zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-zip) are shorter than the length of the array calling the method, `nil`s are appended:

```
> what_has_rolled.zip(how_many_sides)
=> [[nil, 6], [nil, 5], [nil, 4], [4, nil], [1, nil], [3, nil]]
```

To obtain your desired output, you need to ensure that both `what_has_rolled` and `how_many_sides` are of length 3. For example:

```
what_has_rolled = [4,1,3]
how_many_sides = [6,5,4]
what_has_rolled.zip(how_many_sides) do |die, sides| puts "Your d#{sides} rolled a #{die}" end
```

gives the desired output.

Comment: This was exactly the right answer, I had initialized one of the arrays with a given size earlier in the program and then was adding elements on top of it causing several nils to be flooded in. .compact'ing the array showed the answer and then just changing my one line to not fill the array at the beginning fixed it. Thanks Tom!